# data-dropdown-toggle does not open user-dropdown using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a Next.JS project and would like to create a navigation bar similar to the one on [Flowbite](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/#user-menu-dropdown)

```
const NavBar = () => {
  return (
        
    <nav className="bg-white border-gray-200 px-2 sm:px-4 py-2.5 rounded dark:bg-gray-900">
      <div className="container flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto">
      <a href="https://flowbite.com/" className="flex items-center">
          <img src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg" className="h-6 mr-3 sm:h-9" alt="Flowbite Logo" />
          <span className="self-center text-xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">Flowbite</span>
      </a>
      <div className="flex items-center md:order-2">
          <button type="button" className="flex mr-3 text-sm bg-gray-800 rounded-full md:mr-0 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" id="user-menu-button" aria-expanded="false" data-dropdown-toggle="user-dropdown" data-dropdown-placement="bottom">
            <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
            <img className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/357aeb5f4812fb9f69b0e21766c3b31b?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="user photo" />
          </button>
          
          <div className="z-50 hidden my-4 text-base list-none bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded shadow dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600" id="user-dropdown">
            <div className="px-4 py-3">
              <span className="block text-sm text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Bonnie Green</span>
              <span className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 truncate dark:text-gray-400">name@flowbite.com</span>
            </div>
            <ul className="py-1" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button">
              <li>
                <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Dashboard</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Settings</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Earnings</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button data-collapse-toggle="mobile-menu-2" type="button" className="inline-flex items-center p-2 ml-1 text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-controls="mobile-menu-2" aria-expanded="false">
            <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
            <svg className="w-6 h-6" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fillRule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clipRule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
  )
}
    
export default NavBar
```

However, clicking on user's Gravatar does not reveal the drop-down menu/list.

Comment: By the way I am completely new to NextJS, ReactJS, and Tailwind.

Comment: Do you have Flowbite JS installed?

Comment: Yes of-course I have

Comment: I have the same issue here, data-dropdown-toggle not woking.

Comment: i have the same issue. flowbite install perfectly. i can call flowbite Allert as on their sample.